# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-auth-service

This is what I get along with a blank screen. I want a login page where people can register and use their registration to log into the app.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module firebase due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'firebase' is not available! You either 
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module 
>   ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

**Index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-
              scalable=no, width=device-width">
            <title></title>

            <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
            <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
            <script>
              if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
                  .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
                  .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
              }
            </script>-->

            <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Firebase Database -->
           <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.8.0/firebase.js">
          </script>
        <script>
          // Initialize Firebase
          var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyA2D9aQVQEfeKTt1duY1s2kd9zLgTDeHZY",
            authDomain: "health-3d3fd.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://health-3d3fd.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "health-3d3fd",
            storageBucket: "health-3d3fd.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "339252162124"
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>

            <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and 
            remove the CSS includes above
            <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
            -->

            <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
            <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

            <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
            <script src="cordova.js"></script>

            <!-- your app's js -->
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
            <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
            <script src="js/services.js"></script>

          </head>
          <body ng-app="starter">
          <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

          </body>
        </html>
```

**Controllers.js**

```
angular.module("starter")

 .controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope,$firebaseAuth,$rootScope,$ionicHistory,
   sharedUtils,$state,$ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    $rootScope.extras = false;  // For hiding the side bar and nav icon

        // When the user logs out and reaches login page,
        // we clear all the history and cache to prevent back link
        $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(ev) {
          if(ev.targetScope !== $scope){
            $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
            $ionicHistory.clearCache();
          }
        });


        //Check if user already logged in
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
              historyRoot: true
            });
     $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);  // Sets up the sideMenu  dragable
            $rootScope.extras = true;
            sharedUtils.hideLoading();
            $state.go('dashboard', {}, {location: "replace"});

          }
        });

        $scope.login = function(user,cred) {


          if(user.$valid) {  // Check if the form data is valid or not  sharedUtils.showLoading();

              //Email


 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(cred.email,cred.password).then(funct
     ion(result) {

           // You dont need to save the users session as firebase handles it
          // You only need to :
         // 1. clear the login page history from the history stack so that you can’t come back
                    // 2. Set rootScope.extra;
                    // 3. Turn off the loading
                    // 4. Got to menu page

                  $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                    historyRoot: true
                  });
                  $rootScope.extras = true;
                  sharedUtils.hideLoading();
                  $state.go('dashboard', {}, {location: "replace"});

                };
                function(error) {
                  sharedUtils.hideLoading();
                  sharedUtils.showAlert("Please note","Authentication Error");
                }
            );
          }else{
            sharedUtils.showAlert("Please note","Entered data is not valid");
          }

        };

    })

 .controller('RegCtrl',function($scope,$rootScope,sharedUtils,$ionicSideMenuDelegate,$state,fireBaseData,$ionicHistory) {
        $rootScope.extras = false; // For hiding the side bar and nav icon
        $scope.submitForm = function (user, cred) {
          if (user.$valid) {  // Check if the form data is valid or not

            sharedUtils.showLoading();

            //Main Firebase Authentication part

 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(cred.email,cred.password).then(f
   unction (result) {

                //Add name and default dp to the Autherisation table
                result.updateProfile({
                  displayName: cred.name,
                  photoURL: "default_dp"
                }).then(function() {}, function(error) {});

                //Add phone number to the user table
                fireBaseData.refUser().child(result.uid).set({
                  telephone: cred.phone
                });

                //Registered OK
                $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                  historyRoot: true
                });
                $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);  
   // Sets up the sideMenu dragable
                $rootScope.extras = true;
                sharedUtils.hideLoading();
                $state.go('loginpage', {}, {location: "replace"});

            }, function (error) {
                sharedUtils.hideLoading();
                sharedUtils.showAlert("Please note","Registration Error");
            });

          }else{
            sharedUtils.showAlert("Please note","Entered data is not valid");
          }

        }

      })

    .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, formData) {
        $scope.user = formData.getForm();
    })
```

**services.js**

```
.factory('sharedUtils'['$ionicLoading','$ionicPopup',function($ionicLoading,$io
   nicPopup){  
        var functionObj={};
        functionObj.showLoading=function(){
          $ionicLoading.show({
     content: '<i class=" ion-loading-c"></i> ', // The text to display  in the loading indicator
            animation: 'fade-in', // The animation to use
            showBackdrop: true, // Will a dark overlay or backdrop cover the entire view maxWidth: 200,
 // The maximum width of the loading indicator. Text will be wrapped if longer than maxWidth
            showDelay: 0 // The delay in showing the indicator
          });
        };
        functionObj.hideLoading=function(){
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        };


        functionObj.showAlert = function(title,message) {
          var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: title,
            template: message
          });
        };

        return functionObj;

    }])
```

**app.js**

```
  // Ionic Starter App

    // angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving 
     Angular modules
    // 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a 
   <body> attribute in index.html)
    // the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires' angular.module('starter', 
    ['ionic', 'firebase', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the 
    // accessory bar above the keyboard
          // for form inputs)
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
 // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
          // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
          // a much nicer keyboard experience.
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if(window.StatusBar) {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
      });
    })

    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      $stateProvider
        .state('loginpage', {
          url: "/loginpage",
          templateUrl: "templates/loginpage.html",
          controller: "LoginCtrl"
        })
        .state('regform', {
          url: "/regform",
          templateUrl: "templates/regform.html",
          controller: "RegCtrl"
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
          url: "/dashboard",
          templateUrl: "templates/dashboard.html",
          controller: "DashCtrl"
        })

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/loginpage");
    });
```

**Login Page**

```
    <ion-view>
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input ng-model="user.email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input ng-model="user.password" type="text" placeholder="Password">
        </label>
        <button ng-click="login(user)" class="button button-block button-
        positive">Submit</button>

 <center><p>Don't have an account? <a href="/#/regform"> Create Account</a></p>
    </center>

      </ion-content>  
    </ion-view>
```

**Registration Page**

```
 <ion-view>
    <form class="padding">

    <ion-list>
   <ion-item class="item-input">
     <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" placeholder="First Name">
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item class="item-input">
     <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item class="item-input">
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.dob" placeholder="Date of birth"></input>
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item class="item-input">
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.phoneno" placeholder="Phone No."></input>
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item class="item-input">
<input type="text" ng-model="user.gender" placeholder="Male/Female"></input>
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item class="item-input">
 <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email"></input>
   </ion-item>

   <ion-item class="item-input">
  <input type="text" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password"></input>
   </ion-item>

  <button ng-submit="submitForm(user) class="button button-block button-
positive">Register</button>

   <center><p>Don't have an account? <a href="/#/loginpage">Login</a></p>
 </center>

 </ion-list>
</form>
</ion-view>
```

Please can anyone help me out?

Comment: No one is going to help unless you post the minimal code

Comment: this is my first time posting and I want help from that

Comment: That much is obvious, but that code dump hardly qualifies as [mcve], wouldn't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

If the code above is full code of you . Problem is here

```
angular.module("starter")
```

Change to

```
angular.module("starter",[])
```

And you should put your main app in html tag

```
<html ng-app="starter">
```